# How to check array for existing elements to assign ticket numbers?

Tags: php

I am attempting to create a function which will tell me what free numbers are available to use, I have a function which returns the numbers which have already been taken in an array.

I wish to check the returned array with existing elements against a blank array, and if the number is not in the array then push/add it to the empty array to allow me to return an array of available numbers/tickets.

I have tried some examples on here and looked upon PHP documentation on some items trying array_intersect, in_array etc.

I believe the best way to add the free numbers to the empty array is using array_push which has not been implemented into the example code as of yet.

Available numbers function so far:

```
function freeNumbers($drawID){
    $minTickets = 1;
    $maxTickets = totalTickets($drawID);
    $takenNumbers = takenNumbers($drawID);
    $freeNumbers = array();

    for($i = 1; $i<$maxTickets; $i++){
        $x = $i-1;
        foreach($takenNumbers as $v){
            if(in_array($v, $freeNumbers)){
                echo "Element is in array";
                break;
            } else {
                echo $v . "is taken";
            }
        }
    }
    //return $freeNumbers;  
}
```

Taken numbers function

```
function takenNumbers($drawID){
    $connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "dream");
    $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE DrawID = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $drawID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if($result->num_rows == 0) exit("No rows");

    $tickets = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $id = $row['ID'];
        $tickets[] = $row['TicketNumber'];
    }

    return $tickets;
}
```

Max tickets is just counting from a database transaction table to count already assigned numbers.

In this current iteration of the project, I am receiving the following "1 is taken" for each loop.

Thanks in advance, I have attempted to explain what I am attempting to do in best terms possible. But if I haven't been able to describe something please reply so I can explain it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking on each array item, you could get the the difference values between all of the ticket numbers and the taken ticket numbers array using `array_diff()` :

```
function freeNumbers($drawID){
    $minTickets = 1;
    $maxTickets = totalTickets($drawID);
    $takenNumbers = takenNumbers($drawID);
    $freeNumbers = array();

    $allTickets = range(1, $maxTickets);
    $freeNumbers = array_values(array_diff($allTickets, $takenNumbers));
    //return $freeNumbers;  
}
```

Edit : added `array_values()` to reset the array index returned from the `array_diff()` function.

Edit : Or if you prefer to use the `array_push()` function, you could do it like :

```
for($i = 1; $i<$maxTickets; $i++){
    if(!in_array($i, $takenNumbers)){
        array_push($freeNumbers, $i);
    }
}
```